# How to download an modified image loaded by input type="file"

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload

I want to download an image loaded by  that I have modified with filters in javascript but I don't know how to do that, here's the code

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">  
    <img id="output"/>   
       var loadFile = function(event) {
            var output = document.getElementById('output');
            output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            output.onload = function() {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src)
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Not getting your question here. Why do you want to download a file which already exists on your machine, as you just uploaded it?

Comment: Because I'll make modifications on the image

Answer (score 0):

For saving an image, you can create a Canvas element and draw the image in Canvas, then by using its `toDataUrl` method convert and save it.

```
const myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var output = document.getElementById('output');
ctx.drawImage(output, 512, 512);
const dataURL = myCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Also you need some code for saving `dataURL` to a file, later `dataURL` can be use as an `img` source or upload it to server